# IE8 site keeps going into Quirk mode with JS added into the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

We have a site that's running perfectly in all browsers except IE8.

What happens is that it falls into Quirks mode forcefully by the browser due to the reason unknown to me.

And yes, it breaks the site really bad.

What's more weird is that it adds somekind of JS on its own to the code (when checked through View Source.

This is what it's showing:-

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript"> 

<!-- 

document.cookie = "IV_JCT=%2Fapchannel-lop; path=/"; 

//--> 

</SCRIPT> 

<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html lang="en"> 

<head profile="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab"> 

<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
 ...
```

The `<SCRIPT>` in the start is not added by me and is being added by IE8.

I have tried the following

First line `<!DOCTYPE html>` and then right after `<head>`, I wrote `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>`

### Adding respond

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
```

Nothing works.

Any idea how I can stop this and just force it to load with IE8 standard mode?

Thanks

Comment: that's not normal... could the ie be compromised? any plugins we should know about?

Comment: That JS script being added looks like the sort of thing that might be added server-side by your web server. Are you sure that isn't also present in other browsers? Which web server software are you using?

Comment: I am using IE8 and pretty sure that this is not compromised as it's Internal. May be some JS is adding that? May be respond.js?

Comment: never seen anything like that before `<doctype>`which wasn't server generated. Can't imagine script being able to prepend anything outside `<doctype>` either

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're adding the script before the `<!DOCTYPE>`.

The doctype **must** be the very first thing on the page, otherwise IE will go into quirks mode. (even blank lines at the top of the page have been known to affect this)

Move your script somewhere else in the page, ideally inside the `<head>` element, and ensure that you have valid HTML markup, and the problem will resolve itself.

Answer (score 0):

IE 8 will not mangle HTML like that. Something else must be responsible.

From [AJAX techniques within a Tivoli Access Manager WebSEAL Environment](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/tivoli/library/t-ajaxtam/index.html#junction_cookies):

> Junction cookies
>
> Issue
>
> When you create a WebSEAL junction using the -j option to enable
>   junction cookies, special HTML code is inserted at the beginning or
>   end of the HTTP response that sets the correct cookie path in the
>   browser (the location determined by the -j option). Generally, the
>   returned page will look similar to that in Listing 11.
>
> Listing 11. Example of junction cookie insertion
>
> ```
> <SCRIPT>
>     document.cookie = "IV_JCT=%2Fjunction_name";
> </SCRIPT>
>
> <html>
>     <title>Example page </title>
>     <body>
>         Rest of the document...
>         .
>         .
>         .
> ```

That's a pretty specific bit of JavaScript (*Debugging tip: When weird variable names show up in your code and you don't know where they came from: Type them into Google*), so its a reasonable bet that this is what is responsible.

It doesn't sound like there is a work around, so your options seem to come down to:

- Stop using IE 8. It is unsupported by Microsoft and no supported operating system that can run it can't be upgraded to a newer version of IE (they could also be upgraded to a non-IE browser).
- Stop using WebSEAL (or at least WebSEAL junctions using the -j option) since it invalidates your HTML.